# merging returns odd length

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am having a problem with a relatively simple task...

I have two dataframes:
`df_sample` which I read from csv

```
+------+-----------+-------+-----------+
| key  | Full Text | Date  | Publisher |
+------+-----------+-------+-----------+
| abcd | foofoo    | date1 | a         |
| bcde | barbar    | date2 | b         |
| cdef | foobar    | date3 | c         |
+------+-----------+-------+-----------+

len(df_sample) = 20000
```

`df_labels` which I read from excel

```
+------+----------+--------+--------+
| key  | relevant | other  | other2 |
+------+----------+--------+--------+
| abcd | yes      | blabla | blabla |
| bcde | no       | blabla | blabla |
| cdef | no       | blabla | blabla |
| defg | yes      | blabla | blabla |
+------+----------+--------+--------+

len(df_labels) = 219000
```

I would like to join both tables on key assigning `relevant` value for each key from the first dataframe. The desired output would be like this:

```
+------+-----------+-------+-----------+----------+
| key  | Full Text | Date  | Publisher | relevant |
+------+-----------+-------+-----------+----------+
| abcd | foofoo    | date1 | a         | yes      |
| bcde | barbar    | date2 | b         | no       |
| cdef | foobar    | date3 | c         | no       |
+------+-----------+-------+-----------+----------+
```

I seem to achieve that but why the following gives me 27377 results instead of 20000 (as in original left table):

```
df = pd.merge(left=df_sample, right=df_labels, on="key")
```

Comment: have you checked that the key column values are unique in second df, if they are repeated then you get repeated rows, additionally do you have `NaN` in either key column?

Comment: of course, there were some duplicates in the second df... Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing additional rows because the keys are not unique across both dfs, in your case the second df. You'll need to decide whether you want repeated rows which is the current behaviour or you want to drop the duplicates in the second df:

```
df_labels = df_labels.drop_duplicates(subset='key')
```

this will by default keep just the first duplicate, if you want alternate behaviour such as keep last, then you can pass: `keep='last'` see the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)